# How to generate heap dump using jrockit in Windows machine

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, heap-dump, jrockit

I need to generate a heap dump.
jrockit is being used for java and I have installed weblogic on a Windows PC and not Unix.

I can find many answers/command for generating heap dump in unix but none for windows.

I have two managed servers and wish to get a generated heap dump and store it in my PC.
Not able to find a way out.

Comment: seems like none of the weblogic experts are available..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below statement in your startWLSServer.cmd.

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=<<location of file>>
```

This would work only if your jrockit version is R28 and above

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command to get the heap dump in Windows

Syntax:

jrcmd  hprofdump filename=c:\temp\heapdump.hprof

The jrcmd tool is available in JAVA_HOME\bin

Example:

CmdLine> C:\ProgramFiles\java\jdk1.5\bin\jrcmd 1234 hprofdump filename=c:\temp\heapdump.hprof